# android app communication with server dynamically with functions

Tags: java, android, server-side

I'm writing a server side for my android Java application, and I dont really know how to implement what I need.
When a button is clicked in my app, I send a String to the server to start a timer. The server does start a timer and print the numbers to the console.
The server communicate with the client with sockets, and I'm using Async Task to run it.
I want to send a TextView to be modified so that the countdown will be presented in it.

I found it very confusing for how to run the server and to handle requests from the client.
How can I write a server that listen to requests from the client and handle each request with the suitable function?

I am a bit familiar with Play framework, in which you can send GET and POST requests from the client, and in the server side you can handle each requests with the appropriate function.
Is there anything like this that can help me?

Comment: Is the server written in Java as well? Are you familiar with the Servlet API?

Comment: Yes the server is written in Java.
And no I'm now familiar with Servlet..